# Get selected text from a drop-down list but remove numeric value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I'm using a Bootstrap dropdown menu and jQuery to change the default `<span class="selected">All</span>` with the dropdown list item a user selects. However, **I want to only show the text of the selected item**, NOT the numeric item count associated with each item.

IE: If I select:
`<a href="#dropdowns">Sample Text A <span class="badge">3</span></a>` from the list, I only want "Sample Text A" to appear in place of the default "All" text within: `<span class="selected">All</span>`

```js
// TOGGLE Dropdown Selection
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.dropdown-menu a').click(function(){
        $('.selected').text($(this).text());
      });
    });
```

```html
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<div class="dropdown"><br />
        <button class="btn-lg btn-default-outline dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><br />
            <span class="selected">All</span>
      <span class="pull-right fa fa-chevron-down"></span>
     </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li class="dropdown-item">
                <a href="#dropdowns">All <span class="badge">43</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-item">
               <a href="#dropdowns">Sample Text A <span class="badge">3</span></a>
      </li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">
                <a href="#dropdowns">Sample Text B <span class="badge">30</span></a>
      </li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">
                <a href="#dropdowns">Sample Text C <span class="badge">10</span></a>
      </li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">
                <a href="#dropdowns">Sample Text D <span class="badge">40</span></a>
      </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: I updated the code to look for element of .dropdown-menu not dropdown-list.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
 to replace by `''` the text in the `.badge` span element:

```js
$('.dropdown a').click(function(){
  var $li = $(this);
  var badgeText = $li.find('.badge').text();
  var liText = $li.text().replace(new RegExp(badgeText),'');
  
  $('.selected').text(liText);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<div class="dropdown">
   <br />
   <button class="btn-lg btn-default-outline dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><br />
   <span class="selected">All</span>
   <span class="pull-right fa fa-chevron-down"></span>
   </button>
   <ul class="view dropdown-menu">
      <li class="dropdown-item">
         <a href="#dropdowns">All <span class="badge">43</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-item">
         <a href="#dropdowns">Sample Text A <span class="badge">3</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-item">
         <a href="#dropdowns">Sample Text B <span class="badge">30</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-item">
         <a href="#dropdowns">Sample Text C <span class="badge">10</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-item">
         <a href="#dropdowns">Sample Text D <span class="badge">40</span></a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That produces the my desired result.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to acheive this, probably the simplest would be to hide the number in the display e.g.

```
 $('.selected').text($(this).text());
 $('.selected').find('.badge').hide();
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use like this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown-item a').on('click', function() {
    $('.selected').text(($(this).clone().children().remove().end().text()));
  });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://fiddle.jshell.net/e3o4thw7/1/)

Comment: Post your code along with an explanation in your answer